# Using ng-option with sorting and custom text

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have the following ng-repeat:

```
<select class="action-dropdown fade" ng-model="item_value">
    <option value="" disabled>Choose an Step</option>
    <option ng-repeat="step in steps | orderBy:'+step_number'" ng-if="step.step_number >= active_step" value="{{$index}}">Step {{step.step_number}}</option>
</select>
```

I am attempting to change this to an `ng-option` because the following option is popping up and I think this might fix the issue:

```
<option value="? string:5 ?"></option>
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to include my ng-if statement with the `ng-option` and to use the word **Step `$index`** when displaying the option.

The comprehension expressions are just blowing my mind and I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

This is what I have so far:

```
<select class="action-dropdown fade" ng-model="item_value" ng-options="$index as step.step_number for step in steps" required>
    <option value="" disabled>Choose a Step</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think that the best way (cleaner way) is populate the steps list on change `active_step`. To access the index you can use the `(key,value)` syntax.

Comment: @rogeriolino is this with ng-options or ng-repeat

Comment: ngOptions, look the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: @rogeriolino roger, if I understood this doc this question would be irrelevant

Comment: @GrayFox that is neither correct or has anything to do with my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look the snipped as I've commented

> I think that the best way (cleaner way) is populate the steps list on change active_step. To access the index you can use the (key,value) syntax

```
select as label for (key , value) in object
```

Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('DefaultController', function () {
    this.item_value = null;
    this.steps = [ 
        { step_number: 5 }, 
        { step_number: 2 },  
        { step_number: 6 },
        { step_number: 3 },
     { step_number: 1 }, 
        { step_number: 4 },
    ]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <select ng-model="ctrl.item_value" ng-options="step as 'Step ' + index for (index, step) in ctrl.steps | orderBy:'+step_number'" required>
    <option value="" disabled>Choose a Step</option>
</select>
    
    Selected: {{ ctrl.item_value }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks roger, this makes a bit more sense. Is there a way to order by an attribute because I'm afraid in my use case they won't all be in the same order

Comment: You can use the `orderBy` filter as in your original code (I've updated my answer).

Comment: Thanks roger, the biggest `?` i'm trying to solve is the `ng-if ` part

Comment: Create a function to do it on `active_step` change: `steps = allSteps.filter(step => step.step_number >= active_step)`